# Dephi: faster way to convert a “dirty” string to a number

Tags: delphi

How can I make this code faster? the string can contain characters such as ", .?#" and possibly others.

```
Const Nums = ['0'..'9'];

function CleanNumber(s: String): Int64;
Var z: Cardinal;
begin
  for z := length(s) downto 1 do
   if not (s[z] in Nums) then Delete(s,z,1);
  if s = '' then
    Result := 0 else
    Result := StrToInt64(s);
end;
```

Results (long loop):
CL2,CL3 = HeartWare's

*32-bit, "dirty number" / "clean number"*

- Mine: 270ms, 165ms
- CL2: 220ms, 210ms
- CL3: **100ms**, 110ms
- DirtyStrToNum: 215ms, **90ms**

*64-bit, "dirty number" / "clean number"*

- Mine: 2280ms, 75ms
- CL2: 1320ms, 130ms
- CL3: **280ms**, **25ms**
- DirtyStrToNum: 1390ms, 125ms

Comment: your delete statement will reallocate a new string each time. Just use a for loop and buildup a new string only containing numbers.

Comment: Although the answers below answer your actual question, I'd also like to point out that in some cases it might not be a good idea to use a function like this. If a bug or user error makes a street address populate a variable/DB field/edit field supposed to be used for a quantity, you likely want to display an error message instead of silently accepting the street address ("Storgatan 5") as the quantity (5). If you have codes in a specific format (like "123-456#6"), write a parser for that precise format instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two examples that for sure are faster than the one you have (deleting a character from a string is relatively slow):

This one works by pre-allocating a string of the maximum possible length and then filling it out with the digits as I come across them in the source string. No delete for every unsupported character, and no expansion of the target string for every supported character.

```
FUNCTION CleanNumber(CONST S : STRING) : Int64;
  VAR
    I,J : Cardinal;
    C   : CHAR;
    T   : STRING;

   BEGIN
     SetLength(T,LENGTH(S));
     J:=LOW(T);
     FOR I:=LOW(S) TO HIGH(S) DO BEGIN
       C:=S[I];
       IF (C>='0') AND (C<='9') THEN BEGIN
         T[J]:=C;
         INC(J)
       END
     END;
     IF J=LOW(T) THEN
       Result:=0
     ELSE BEGIN
       SetLength(T,J-LOW(T));  // or T[J]:=#0 [implementation-specific]
       Result:=StrToInt64(T)
     END
   END;
```

This one works by simple multiplication of the end result by 10 and adding the corresponding digit value.

```
 {$IFOPT Q+}
   {$DEFINE OverflowEnabled }
 {$ELSE }
   {$Q+ If you want overflow checking }
 {$ENDIF }
 FUNCTION CleanNumber(CONST S : STRING) : Int64;
   VAR
     I  : Cardinal;
     C  : CHAR;

   BEGIN
     Result:=0;
     FOR I:=LOW(S) TO HIGH(S) DO BEGIN
       C:=S[I];
       IF (C>='0') AND (C<='9') THEN Result:=Result*10+(ORD(C)-ORD('0'))
     END
   END;
 {$IFNDEF OverflowEnabled } {$Q-} {$ENDIF }
 {$UNDEF OverflowEnabled }
```

Also note that I don't use IN or CharInSet as these are much slower than a simple inline >= and <= comparison.

Another comment I could make is the use of LOW and HIGH on the string variable. This makes it compatible with both 0-based strings (mobile compilers) and 1-based strings (desktop compilers).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193629/discussion-on-answer-by-heartware-dephi-faster-way-to-convert-a-dirty-string).

Answer (score 2):

Your function is slow mainly because of the `Delete` approach. Each call to `Delete` needs to move a lot of characters around.

A faster approach would be like this:

```
function DirtyStrToNum(const S: string): Int64;
var
  tmp: string;
  i, j: Integer;
const
  DIGITS = ['0'..'9'];
begin
  SetLength(tmp, S.Length);
  j := 0;
  for i := 1 to S.Length do
    if CharInSet(S[i], DIGITS) then
    begin
      Inc(j);
      tmp[j] := S[i];
    end;
  SetLength(tmp, j);
  if tmp.IsEmpty then
    Result := 0
  else
    Result := StrToInt64(tmp);
  // Or, but not equivalent: Result := StrToInt64Def(tmp, 0);
end;
```

Notice I make a single allocation for a new string, and then only copy the minimum number of characters to it.

Comment: Again two heap allocations. This is possible without any heap allocations.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Indeed, it is certainly possible to improve further.

Comment: There aren't any Delphi rtl functions to convert from a fixed length character array to integer, or indeed other types. Very frustrating that the rtl pushes us to use the heap for such tasks. I'm currently working on optimising a text file parser for simple files full of numbers. Galling to have the rtl insist on using the heap. Forces me to write my own functions to perform the conversions.

Comment: I see only 1 heap allocation. The "truncation" of the tmp variable does not necessarily result in a heap re-allocation but most likely only in an update of the length field in the string record (depending on the memory manager and the specific length of the initial allocation).